# Binding a JSON to a bean with a key which can be map or an array at times

Tags: java, json, javabeans

I have a dynamic incoming JSON like shown below :

1. 1st possibility

   ```
   {
   "key1":"value1",
   "key2":"value2",
   "key3":{
          "inKey1":"inValue1",
          "inKey2":"inValue2"
          }
   }
   ```
2. 2nd possibility

   ```
   { "key1":"value1", "key2":"value2", "key3":[{
          "inKey1":"inValue1",
           "inKey2":"inValue2"
           },{
           "inKey1":"inValue3",
           "inKey2":"inValue4"
      }] }
   ```

   The value of key3 is generally a map. But sometimes it can come as an array as well. I have to bind this JSON to a Bean and then proceed further. I am planning to write two beans, one with key3 as a map and the other with key3 as an array. I will check if value of key3 is an instance of map or an array and then bind to the corresponding bean. Is there any optimal way to get this task done with a single bean ? Please guide me.

Beans (which I havent written yet) would be something like :

```
public class Bean1{

private String key1;
private String key2;
private Map<String, String> key3 = new HashMap<String, String>();

}

public class Bean2{

private String key1;
private String key2;
private Map<String, String> key3[];

}
```

Comment: Please Show your code of at least one of the beans

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Deserialization of different json inputs with common properties can be done through generalization (Inheritance).

**Define a parent bean :** Define a parent bean with common properties

```
public class ParentBean {

    protected String key1;
    protected String key2;

    public ParentBean(String key1, String key2) {
        super();
        this.key1 = key1;
        this.key2 = key2;
    }
    // Setters and Getters
}
```

**Define child beans :** Define child beans with special properties

**Bean1**

```
public class Bean1 extends ParentBean {

    private Map<String, String> key3;

    public Bean1(String key1, String key2, Map<String, String> key3) {
        super(key1, key2);
        this.key3 = key3;
    }
    // Setters and Getters
}
```

**Bean2**

```
public class Bean2 extends ParentBean {

    private Map<String, String> key3[];

    public Bean2(String key1, String key2, Map<String, String>[] key3) {
        super(key1, key2);
        this.key3 = key3;
    }
    // Setters and Getters
}
```

**Design a Deserializer :** Since the framework is not specified, I have taken the liberty of using jackson framwork. Using jackson a Deserializer can be designed as follows:

```
public class ParentBeanDeserializer extends StdDeserializer<ParentBean>{

    public ParentBeanDeserializer() { 
        this(null); 
    } 

    public ParentBeanDeserializer(Class<?> c) { 
        super(c); 
    }   

    @Override
    public ParentBean deserialize(JsonParser jp, DeserializationContext ctxt) 
        throws IOException, JsonProcessingException{

        ParentBean pb;
        JsonNode node = jp.getCodec().readTree(jp);
        String value1 = node.findValue("key1").asText();
        String value2 = node.findValue("key2").asText();
        JsonNode node3 = node.findValue("key3");
        ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();

        if(node3.isArray()){
            String json3 = node3.toString();
            Map<String, String>[] map = mapper.readValue(json3, Map[].class);
            pb = new Bean2(value1,value2,map);
        }
        else{
            String json3 = node3.toString();
            Map<String, String> map = mapper.readValue(json3, Map.class);
            pb = new Bean1(value1,value2,map);
        }

        return pb;
    }

}
```

**Usage :** Beans/Classes mentioned above can be used as follows:

```
     String json = getJasonResponseAsText();
     ObjectMapper om = new ObjectMapper();
     SimpleModule mod = new SimpleModule();
     mod.addDeserializer(ParentBean.class, new ParentBeanDeserializer());
     om.registerModule(mod);
     ParentBean pb = om.readValue(json, ParentBean.class);
     if (pb instanceof Bean1) {
           Bean1 b1 = (Bean1)pb;
           //Perform Bean1 related activites
     } 
     else if (pb instanceof Bean2) {
           Bean2 b2 = (Bean2)pb;
           //Perform Bean2 related activites
     }
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm using [org.json](https://github.com/stleary/JSON-java) the main thing is to check whether the key is instanceof object or array. when you get to know the kind of the key. you can put your logic easily.

In the first case you have object then i simply typecast into object and fetch the values.

in the second case you have the array so i typecast into JSONArary and  used a simple for loop to gather the elements.

Code:

```
package jsontest;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import org.json.JSONArray;
import org.json.JSONObject;
/**
 *
 * @author Sahil
 */
class Model1{
    String key1;
    String key2;
    List<Model2> key3;
    Model1(){
        key3 = new ArrayList<>();
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {  
        String s = "key1=" + key1 + ", key2=" + key2;
        for(Model2 m: key3){
            s+="\n"+"inKey1="+m.key1+", inkey2="+m.key2;
        }  
        return s;
    }

}
class Model2{
   String key1;
   String key2;
}



public class JSONTest {


    static Model1 parse(String s){
         JSONObject object = new JSONObject(s);
        Model1 model = new Model1();
        model.key1 = object.getString("key1");
        model.key2 = object.getString("key2");

        if (object.get("key3") instanceof JSONObject){
            JSONObject key3 = object.getJSONObject("key3");
            Model2 model2 = new Model2();
            model2.key1 = key3.getString("inKey1");
            model2.key2 = key3.getString("inKey2");
            model.key3.add(model2);

        }else{
            JSONArray array = object.getJSONArray("key3");
            for(int i=0;i<array.length();i++){
                JSONObject row = array.getJSONObject(i);
                Model2 model2 = new Model2();
                model2.key1 = row.getString("inKey1");
                model2.key2 = row.getString("inKey2");
                model.key3.add(model2);
            }
        }
        return model;
    }


    /**
     * @param args the command line arguments
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String firstCase = "{\r\n\"key1\":\"value1\",\r\n\"key2\":\"value2\",\r\n\"key3\":{\r\n       \"inKey1\":\"inValue1\",\r\n       \"inKey2\":\"inValue2\"\r\n       }\r\n}";
        String secondCase = "{ \"key1\":\"value1\", \"key2\":\"value2\", \"key3\":[{\r\n       \"inKey1\":\"inValue1\",\r\n        \"inKey2\":\"inValue2\"\r\n        },{\r\n        \"inKey1\":\"inValue3\",\r\n        \"inKey2\":\"inValue4\"\r\n   }] }";
        System.out.println(parse(firstCase));
        System.out.println("---------");
        System.out.println(parse(secondCase));

    }

}
```

Result:

```
key1=value1, key2=value2
inKey1=inValue1, inkey2=inValue2
---------
key1=value1, key2=value2
inKey1=inValue1, inkey2=inValue2
inKey1=inValue3, inkey2=inValue4
```